# Random Positive Definite matrix and Cholesky decomposition

Tags: python, random, linear-algebra

I was interested in generating the correlated random data set and found some example of the solution [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of). But I've faced some interesting problems.

The solution consists from the next steps:

1. Generate random uncorrelated data points (maybe from normal destribution)
2. Calculate their covariance matrix (it must be positive definite)
3. Find Cholesky decomposition of the covariance matrix

But the realization failing, if I am generating random points in the non-square form. For example:

```
X = np.random.rand(1000, 140)
Omega = np.cov(X)
# or 
# Omega = np.dot(X_uncorr, X_uncorr.transpose())
# or 
# Omega = np.corrcoef(X.T, X.T, rowvar=False)
```

than the functions scipy.linalg.cholesky() and np.linalg.cholesky() will rise an errors 'LinAlgError: 101-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite' and  'LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite' correspondingly.

If the original data symmetric:

```
X = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
```

there will be no errors. Is it some math fact, that the Cov matrix of nonsymmetric data set is negative definite? Or is it an error in code realization?

Comment: Positive definite matrices must be symmetric. The entries in a covariance matrix cannot be arbitrary random numbers, they must yield eigenvalues which are all positive. Another observation that any old random numbers won't do is that Correlation(X,Y) = Cov(X,Y)/sqrt(Var(X)*Var(Y)) and must have a magnitude ≤ 1, so |Cov(X,Y)| ≤ sqrt(Var(X)*Var(Y)) is a requirement.

Comment: @pjs Thank you, I am generating not a random entries of the covariance matrix, by random set of points and calculate it's Cov matrix

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/386542

Comment: @Sanxofon but why is it impossible to calculate the Cov (X, X.T), it should be symmetric and p.d. Where it doesn't work?

Comment: if X = np.random.rand(1000, 150), than np.shape(Cov(X,X.T)) = (1000,1000), we are just calculating cov for any pair of X matrix rows